# How read couple of log files and split them on in lines on pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dir with log files all ending with *.log
Is it possible to read all files make one big file and split the lines on finding a "date"
The log files looks something like this:

```
2019-04-15 21:58:07 bla bla bla
2019-04-15 21:58:08 bla bla bla bla
2019-04-15 21:58:09 bla bla bla
test1
test2
test3
2019-04-15 21:59:02 bla bla
2019-04-15 21:59:05 bla bla bla
test
now
go
```

Now i would like to split this file in lines when finding a date so that it would be like:

```
2019-04-15 21:58:07 bla bla bla
2019-04-15 21:58:08 bla bla bla bla
2019-04-15 21:58:09 bla bla bla test1 test2 test3
2019-04-15 21:59:02 bla bla
2019-04-15 21:59:05 bla bla bla test now go
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Kind regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? If so what errors are you running into?

Comment: I have tried to o some thing with regex like search for a pattern

pattern = re.compile("([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))")  # yyy-mm-dd

but cant seem to make the good code to get the above result

Comment: import os, re

log = open("log.log", "r")
text = log.read()
lon = re.compile("([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))", re.MULTILINE)
lon = lon.search(text).group(1)
print(lon)

Comment: @R. Arctor, can you help me please?

Comment: So for clarity's sake, you want to 1. concatenate all logs in some directory into a single file. 2. Move lines without the leading date string to the last line with a leading data string. 3. Write modified and concatenated logs to a "master" log file. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah! youre right! thats the wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty and it could probably be more efficient but this works

```py
import os, re

# change this to be wherever you keep all those log files
work_dir = '/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/tmp'

# load the full path for all files in the work_dir (I'm not checking if file is a .log file)
logs = [os.path.join(work_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(work_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(work_dir, file))]


def process_list(in_list):
    date_patt = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s]+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
    last_good_idx = 0
    for idx in range(len(in_list)):
        if re.search(date_patt, in_list[idx]):
            last_good_idx = idx
        else:
            in_list[last_good_idx] += f' {in_list[idx].strip()}'

    return in_list

def clean_list(in_list):
    date_patt = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s]+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
    for elem in in_list[:]:
        if not re.search(date_patt, elem):
            in_list.remove(elem)
    return in_list

# write master log to working directory file called master.log
with open(os.path.join(work_dir, 'master.log'), 'w') as out:
    for file in logs:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            file_text = f.read()
            text_list = file_text.split('\n')
            text_list = process_list(text_list)
            text_list = clean_list(text_list)

            for line in text_list:
                out.write(line + '\n')
```

If you only wanted to use files ending in .log add it to the list comprehension that assigns the `logs` variable.

`process_list` handles moving lines which don't match the `date_patt` regex to the end of the string found at the last index where the `date_patt` was matched.

`clean_list` removes any element from the input list that doesn't match the `date_patt`.

Comment: SUPER! perfect!

Comment: No problem, let me know if there's a part you don't understand, or need help improving.

Comment: there is one thing, is it possible to check every subdir from the work dir "./" for *.log files and make one master file of it? now it check only the work dir and no futjer

Comment: That sort of thing has been answered on here plenty of times. See if you can work it out yourself, if you can't post what you've tried and whatnot. Helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python